# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message: all of my commands?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hey I have an error : `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`
Of all my command ! Here is my code when I send `-help` so I regenerate the token and it's don't work and I create a new folder with the same code and it's don't work but my other bot work perfectionnaly in discordjs v12 but I'm in discordjs v13 (because we must change)

````
const config = require('../config/config.json')

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  const prefix = config.prefix
  const HelpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Help")
    .setColor('RED')
    .setFooter(`Demandé par ${message.author.tag}`)
    .addFields(
      {
        name: "ADMINISTRATEUR",
        value: `${prefix}ban => Permet de bannir une personne \n${prefix}unban => Permet de unban une personne \n${prefix}kick => Permet de kick une personne \n${prefix}prefix => Permet de changer le prefix (owner seulement)`,
        inline: true
      },
      {
        name: "MODÉRATION",
        value: `${prefix}nuke => Permet de nuke un salon \n${prefix}embed => Permet de créer un embed interactif \n${prefix}mute => Permet de mute une personne \n${prefix}unmute => Permet d'unmute une personne \n${prefix}warn => Permet de warn une personne (whitelist)`,
        inline: true
      },
      {
        name: "FUN",
        value: `${prefix}stats => Stats du serveur(en dev) \n${prefix}userinfo => Permet d'avoir des informations sur une personne \n${prefix}serveur => Permet d'avoir des informations sur le serveur \n${prefix}snipe => Montre le dernier message supprimmer par une personne \n${prefix}say => Permet de faire dire au bot quelque chose \n${prefix}vc => Permet devoir le nombre de personnes en vocal sur le serveur \n${prefix}giveaway => Permet de créé un giveaway \n${prefix}panel-gw => Permet de construire un giveaway interactif`,
        inline: true
      },
      {
        name: "OWNER / OWNER LISTE",
        value: `${prefix}owner => Liste des owners \n${prefix}addowner => Ajouter un owner à l'owner liste \n${prefix}unowner => Supprimme un owner de l'owner liste \n${prefix}wl => Liste des membres dans la whitelist \n${prefix}addwl => Ajouter un membre dans la whitelist \n${prefix}unwl => Supprimme un membre de la whitelist \n${prefix}soutien => Ajoute un rôle au personnes qui ont un status \n${prefix}antilink => Active / désactive l'anti-link \n${prefix}antiraid => Active / désactive l'anti-raid \n${prefix}antispam => Active / désactive l'anti-spam \n${prefix}webhook => Active / désactive l'anti-webhook \n${prefix}secur => Active / désactive l'anti-spam, link, raid, webhook`,
        inline: true
      },
      {
        name: "LOGS",
        value: `${prefix}joinlog => Permet de configurer le salon de join-log \n${prefix}leavelog => Permet de configurer le salon de leave-log \n${prefix}messagelog => Permet de configurer le salon de message-log \n${prefix}raidlog => Permet de configurer le salon de raid-log \n${prefix}voicelog => Permet de configurer le salon de voice-log`,
        inline: true
      },
      {
        name: 'BACKUP',
        value: `${prefix}backup-create => Créé une backup du serveur \n${prefix}backup-info => Permet d'avoir des informations sur une backup \n${prefix}backup-load => Permet de load une backup sur le serveur`
      })
  message.reply({ embeds: [HelpEmbed] })
}```

Thanks for your answer ! (I'm on discord v13)
````

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the objects inside addFields inside an array, something like this:-

```js
.addFields([
      {
        name: "ADMINISTRATEUR",
        value: `${prefix}ban => Permet de bannir une personne \n${prefix}unban => Permet de unban une personne \n${prefix}kick => Permet de kick une personne \n${prefix}prefix => Permet de changer le prefix (owner seulement)`,
        inline: true
      },
      // ... more stuff
      {
        name: 'BACKUP',
        value: `${prefix}backup-create => Créé une backup du serveur \n${prefix}backup-info => Permet d'avoir des informations sur une backup \n${prefix}backup-load => Permet de load une backup sur le serveur`,
        inline: true
      }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

`Discord` is not defined, you can fix this by adding this line at the start of your code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
```